# I am obviously not a thief!

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, lateral-thinking, word-property

*Tearing from fearing,

Thumbs nervously interlocking because of the robbing,

Since the cheating done in that meeting,

So in the center of a dark alley I hide,

Like a rudiment the heart pounds at my side!*

*If each of these lines you truly understand,

Then you would know exactly what I am!* (6)

Comment: Re: your comment on the bounty: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5887/21369

Comment: Very true. I think I have severely underestimated its difficulty I thought it was easy and would be solved within a few hours.